Can we set the height and width of a text element in JasperReports using parameters or fields?
I am working with JasperReports and need to dynamically set the height and width of an image field based on parameters passed from the backend.
I tried passing the width and height so the image gets resized, and I set scaleImage="Real Size" to display the image at its actual size. However, this causes a reduction in quality in the report.
Does anyone have an idea on how to display an image with a dynamic size passed from the backend without reducing its quality?
 int targetWidth = 100; // Adjust the target width as needed
            int targetHeight = 100; // Adjust the target height as needed

            // Create a new buffered image with the desired dimensions
            BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(targetWidth, targetHeight, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

            // Use Graphics2D to perform the scaling
            Graphics2D g2d = resizedImage.createGraphics();
            g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
            // Set rendering hints for better quality
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);

            // Draw the original image into the resized image
            g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, targetWidth, targetHeight, null);

            // Dispose of the graphics context
            g2d.dispose();

            // Put the resized image into the parameters map
            parameters.put(Constants.LOGO.toUpperCase(), resizedImage);

